Too Many Pythons?
I use a MacBook Pro 2019 running Sonoma 14.3.1
I've installed and uninstalled Python (using Homebrew, and Python.org installers, and asdf) and changed my $PATH a million times.
At present I can't really figure out what I've got, but something seems off. In my .zprofile I have aliased python to python3, but without that, the terminal doesn't know what "python" is. I would have to run python3.
If I
which python3

I get:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3

Which is maybe consistent with how the Python.org installer situates python?
The python.org installer automatically overwrites the .zprofile with a path variable update so that the zsh $PATH variable looks like this:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes... etc.

I type
which -a python3 

I get
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

And both
python3 -V

and
usr/local/bin/python3 -V

show
Python 3.12.4

but:
usr/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.9.6

My questions are:
Do I have a problem?
Does it need to be solved?
Is there something I can do besides aliasing python to python3 to make the command 'python' execute python?
If I just want to play around and learn and grow as a coder using various coding tools (IDLE, BBEdit, MuEditor, Jupyter, etc). Do I need to set up my system differently?
Do I need Pyenv Rye or something like that?
I have tried and tried to figure out how to make sure I have Python properly installed and I remain confused.

"Do I need Pyenv?" yes (though virtualenv will do, you just won't be able to select specific python versions) You need virtual envs from the start. The rest of the question I have no comment on

To answer one of your questions, you don't have any problem that I can see. I do advise also that you get used to using python virtual environments from the start (venv is fine if you are using Mac) - its a little confusing but just do what any of a dozen different tutorials tell you and get going.

on LInux Mint command /usr/bin/python3 -V shows 3.10 and I don't change it because this version was installed with system, and system may use it for some functions. But I have also installed other versions and I can use command python3.11 python3.12. python3.13 or even python3.9, python3.8, python3.7 (and the same pip3.10, pip3.11, pip3.12, etc.) so if I needs not standard version than I can simply use other command. BTW: all of them are use similar path /usr/bin/python3.10,/usr/bin/python3.11, etc so I don't have to change PATH`.
